# How to determine which Brackets extension is causing a bug (breaking ctrl-c keybinding)

Tags: adobe, adobe-brackets

I just started using Adobe Brackets today. I grabbed a handful of extensions during setup and subsequently lost ctrl-c to copy text. I reloaded the project without extensions and the keybinding works. Reloading with extensions and keybinding doesn't work.

I would like to disable extensions individually but it appears I can only remove them. Is there a way to debug individual extensions without removing them?

(in the meantime, I removed the offending extension but I am still very interested in answers to my question, thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can disable extensions individually: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#disabling-extensions-individually

TLDR: you can't do it from the Extension Manager UI, but you can just temporarily move extensions to a different folder to disable them.